# What is the best free ETL to extract Data from Cassandra 3.10 ?

Tags: database, cassandra, etl, iot

I want to extract Data from my database Cassandra, and do some transformations.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the spark connector

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, one of the best ETL is Pentaho Data Integrator.

It is free, easy to learn, robust to use. It has a Cassandra connector since 2012, tested and well documented with [tutorials](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Cassandra) and stackover flow tags.

Comment: Pentaho Data Intagration is not compatible with Cassandra vesion 3.10

Comment: @Kikou Hi and new tool found that supports Cassandra version 3.10? I want to extract data form Cassandra and transform by adding columns and send it to other db